# 'sudo dnf update' package conflicts on Fedorda Rawhide 37

Tags: linux, fedora, package-management, dnf

Below is my output from trying to update my packages using dnf update.

I'm new to the rawhide community. I'm not sure if this is an error on the package maintainers end and it will resolve itself?

I can't remove the conflicting  package without it warning me it'll remove gnome.

I've also run a dnf clean but it didn't work either.

Is this something I can fix out? Or is this something that the package maintainers will fix soon enough?

I understand this is beta, was curious how often breaks like this happen as well.

Thanks!

```
 sudo dnf update        
Last metadata expiration check: 0:05:29 ago on Mon 08 Aug 2022 02:59:00 PM EDT.
Dependencies resolved.
================================================================================
 Package                   Arch        Version               Repository    Size
================================================================================
Upgrading:
 glibc                     x86_64      2.36-1.fc37           rawhide      2.1 M
 glibc-all-langpacks       x86_64      2.36-1.fc37           rawhide       18 M
 glibc-common              x86_64      2.36-1.fc37           rawhide      359 k
 glibc-devel               x86_64      2.36-1.fc37           rawhide       96 k
 glibc-gconv-extra         x86_64      2.36-1.fc37           rawhide      1.6 M
 glibc-headers-x86         noarch      2.36-1.fc37           rawhide      574 k
 glibc-langpack-en         x86_64      2.36-1.fc37           rawhide      676 k
 gsm                       x86_64      1.0.22-1.fc37         rawhide       35 k
 libnsl                    x86_64      2.36-1.fc37           rawhide      121 k
 libwebp                   x86_64      1.2.4-1.fc37          rawhide      278 k
 python3-google-auth       noarch      1:2.10.0-1.fc37       rawhide      248 k
 vulkan-loader             x86_64      1.3.216.0-3.fc37      rawhide      142 k
 webkit2gtk4.1             x86_64      2.37.1-13.fc37        rawhide       18 M
 webkit2gtk4.1-jsc         x86_64      2.37.1-12.fc37        rawhide      6.4 M
Installing dependencies:
 javascriptcoregtk4.1      x86_64      2.37.1-13.fc37        rawhide      6.4 M

Transaction Summary
================================================================================
Install   1 Package
Upgrade  14 Packages

Total download size: 55 M
Is this ok [y/N]: y
Downloading Packages:
(1/15): glibc-2.36-1.fc37.x86_64.rpm            3.5 MB/s | 2.1 MB     00:00    
(2/15): glibc-common-2.36-1.fc37.x86_64.rpm     4.1 MB/s | 359 kB     00:00    
(3/15): glibc-devel-2.36-1.fc37.x86_64.rpm      1.4 MB/s |  96 kB     00:00    
(4/15): glibc-gconv-extra-2.36-1.fc37.x86_64.rp 4.5 MB/s | 1.6 MB     00:00    
(5/15): glibc-headers-x86-2.36-1.fc37.noarch.rp 3.8 MB/s | 574 kB     00:00    
(6/15): glibc-langpack-en-2.36-1.fc37.x86_64.rp 5.1 MB/s | 676 kB     00:00    
(7/15): gsm-1.0.22-1.fc37.x86_64.rpm            612 kB/s |  35 kB     00:00    
(8/15): libnsl-2.36-1.fc37.x86_64.rpm           1.9 MB/s | 121 kB     00:00    
(9/15): libwebp-1.2.4-1.fc37.x86_64.rpm         4.5 MB/s | 278 kB     00:00    
(10/15): python3-google-auth-2.10.0-1.fc37.noar 3.2 MB/s | 248 kB     00:00    
(11/15): vulkan-loader-1.3.216.0-3.fc37.x86_64. 2.2 MB/s | 142 kB     00:00    
(12/15): javascriptcoregtk4.1-2.37.1-13.fc37.x8 3.3 MB/s | 6.4 MB     00:01    
(13/15): webkit2gtk4.1-jsc-2.37.1-12.fc37.x86_6 2.9 MB/s | 6.4 MB     00:02    
(14/15): webkit2gtk4.1-2.37.1-13.fc37.x86_64.rp 6.8 MB/s |  18 MB     00:02    
(15/15): glibc-all-langpacks-2.36-1.fc37.x86_64 910 kB/s |  18 MB     00:20    
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Total                                           2.7 MB/s |  55 MB     00:20     
Running transaction check
Transaction check succeeded.
Running transaction test
The downloaded packages were saved in cache until the next successful transaction.
You can remove cached packages by executing 'dnf clean packages'.
Error: Transaction test error:
  file /usr/lib64/libjavascriptcoregtk-4.1.so.0.2.0 conflicts between attempted installs of webkit2gtk4.1-jsc-2.37.1-12.fc37.x86_64 and javascriptcoregtk4.1-2.37.1-13.fc37.x86_64
```

Comment: You're using Rawhide - breakages are expected. Please try in a day or two.

Answer (score 0):

> Is this something I can fix out?

This is a dependency problem. It might already be solved, or it might need maintainer intervention, in which case you could help upstream, if you know your way around fedora packaging and have knowledge of the affected software.

It probably should not have happened; looks like there's a version bump that's only been partially done. However, note that fedora rawhide is the rolling-release, kind-of-experimental version of Fedora, until at some point they freeze it, start concentrating on fixing (exactly such!) bugs, and then roll the next release if nothing broke for a while. If you want something that you're certain still works after an update, I'd recommend you stick to the current released version of Fedora, and not use Rawhide. At this point in time, that's Fedora 36.

> Or is this something that the package maintainers will fix soon enough?

No guarantees, at all, that this will be fixed before the release of 37. As it's [currently planned](https://fedorapeople.org/groups/schedule/f-37/f-37-key-tasks.html), this might take up to the release of the Beta 2022-09-13, unless it gets a blocker exception, in which case it might live longer!